Tikz loop \foreach element in a set A but not in a set B
Does anyone know what is the command “not in the set” in TikZ? What I want is, let A be a set and B be a subset of A. What is the command in TikZ to tell:
“for each i in A but not in B?
I need something like:
foreach i in A
  if i is in the set B do THIS, else do THAT


Welcome to TeX.SE!

Could you provide some code that shows how you intend the approach to look like? Also, what is the reason for this? There might be other ways to solve your issue ...

Brute force approach.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\setA{1,2,3,4,5}
\def\setB{2,4}

\newif\ifmatch

\begin{document}

\let\setC=\empty
\foreach \x in \setA {\matchfalse
  \foreach \y in \setB {\ifnum\x=\y\relax \global\matchtrue \fi}%
  \ifmatch\else
    \ifx\empty\setC\relax
      \xdef\setC{\x}%
    \else
      \xdef\setC{\setC,\x}%
    \fi
  \fi}

\setC% should contain 1,3,5

\end{document}


We can represent (ordered) sets as comma separated lists.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\foreachnot}{mm+m+m}
 {% #1 = main list, #2 = exclusion list,
  % #3 = to do if item is in main list but not in the exclusion list
  % #4 = to do if item is in the main list and in the exclusion list
  \erdos_forachnot:nnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\definelist}{mm}
 {
  \clist_clear_new:c { l__erdos_list_#1_clist }
  \clist_set:cn { l__erdos_list_#1_clist } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \erdos_forachnot:nnnn
 {
  \cs_set_protected:Nn \__erdos_foreachnot_true:n { #3 }
  \cs_set_protected:Nn \__erdos_foreachnot_false:n { #4 }
  \clist_map_inline:cn { l__erdos_list_#1_clist }
   {
    \clist_if_in:cnTF { l__erdos_list_#2_clist } { ##1 }
     {% item is in main list and in the exclusion list
      \__erdos_foreachnot_false:n { ##1 }
     }
     {% item is in main list but not in the exclusion list
      \__erdos_foreachnot_true:n { ##1 }
     }
   }
 }

% initialize the two scratch functions
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__erdos_foreachnot_true:n {}
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__erdos_foreachnot_false:n {}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\definelist{A}{1,2,3,4,5}
\definelist{B}{2,4}

\foreachnot{A}{B}{Item #1 is in A but not in B\par}{Item #1 is in A and in B\par}

\end{document}

The third and fourth arguments are templates where the current item is denoted by #1.
More work is needed if you need to nest such loops.

